# How to create an alphabet with RexExp object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, alphabet

Is there any solution to create an alphabet with RexExp object? Is this possible ?  As the result I wish to obtain an array with the length of 26 latin letters (law case).
I tried to test my RegExp pattern */a-z+/g* with help of String replace method, but it replaces a space by pattern literally, not by alphabet as I thought.

```js
var test = " ";
var pattern = /a-z+/g;
var result = " ";
var text;
var arr;
  
alert(pattern.test("/a-z+/g"));
text = result.replace(test, pattern);
alert(text);
arr = text.split();
alert(arr.length);
```

Comment: You want to have all the letters that are represented by the `a-z` in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with a regex object. Regexes are for matching against values you already have, rather than creating new ones. You can create the alphabet by looping over character code ranges, if that helps?

```js
var letters = [];
// loop over character codes of the lowercase alphabet
for (var i = 97; i < 123; i++) {
  // push each letter in to the array
  letters.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}
// create an element
var elem = document.createElement('p');
// set the innerHTML to the joined array
elem.innerHTML = letters.join(',');
// put the element on the page
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Thank you @sauntimo, that is what I understood when was playing around RegExp. I accept your solution that use Character Set, it's looks to be the most neat and dynamic way to create an alphabetical / characters array by JS.